# Not able to bind service in activity

Tags: android, pjsip, csip-simple

I am binding service from `SherlockFragment` and binding service in it but connection is not establishing.

```
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {      

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
        service = ISipService.Stub.asInterface(arg1);
        System.out.println("Inside Connection"+service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        service = null;
    }
};
```

Control is never go inside `onServiceConnected()`

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: what is a use for posting empty ServiceConnection? it doesn't tell anything to anyone

Comment: `Binder` mate no class implement karyo che?